# Registry mod to replace PowerShell with CMD in WinX menu (2019 new windows 10 update)

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry

At some point in 2019 Windows 10 updated to where PowerShell is the default in the WinX menu. I'm looking for a solution to change this that can be syspreped and cloned. So a registry modification or non-user specific settings change. Note: There are plenty of explanations out there for changing this in the File Explorer context menu (registry>shell>cmd), but that does not change the WinX menu.

Answer (score 2):

The registry key you are looking for is:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced

You want to create a "DontUsePowerShellOnWinX" DWORD value and set it to 1. The same key also exists under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE if you want the change to apply to all users.

You can then apply the change by opening a File Explorer window (default shortcut is WIN+E), then opening Task Manager and right-clicking "Windows Explorer" -> "Restart"

For those who want an automated way of doing it, copy and paste the following text in Notepad:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced]
"DontUsePowerShellOnWinX"=dword:00000001
```

Then save the file as a .reg file (name doesn't matter). You can then simply double-click the file, or right-click -> Merge. A restart of File Explorer is still required though.

Comment: You can also use this in CMD or from a Batch file:

`reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced\" /v DontUsePowerShellOnWinX /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f`  Additionally, to address the OP's request for a "non user-specific solution" - this MUST be user specific as it's part of the specific user's Hive and cannot be made as a global switch AFAIK.